# How to automate PDF form-filling in Java

Tags: java, forms, pdf, itext

I am doing some "pro bono" development for a food pantry near where I live. They are inundated with forms and paperwork, and I would like to develop a system that simply reads data from their MySQL server (which I set up for them on a previous project) and feeds data into PDF versions of all the forms they are required to fill out. This will help them out enormously and save them a lot of time, as well as get rid of a lot of human errors that are made when filling out these forms.

Not knowing *anything* about the internals of PDF files, I can foresee two avenues here:

- **Harder Way**: It is possible to scan a paper document, turn it into a PDF, and then have software that "fills out" the PDF simply by saying "add text except *blah* to the following (x,y) coordinates..."; or
- **Easier Way**: PDF specification already allows for the construct of "fields" that can be filled out; this way I just write code that says "add text excerpt *blah* to the field called *address_value*...", etc.

So my first question is: which of the two avenues am I facing? Does PDF have a concept of "fields" or do I need to "fill out" these documents by telling the PDF library the pixel coordinates of where to place data?

Second, I obviously need an open source (and Java) library to do this. iText seems to be a good start but I've heard it can be difficult to work with. Can anyone lend some ideas or general recommendations here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can easily merge data into PDF's fields using the FDF(Form Data Format) technology.

Adobe provides a library to do that :  [Acrobat Forms Data Format (FDF) Toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html)

Also [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html) can be used to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RealHowTo, but the FDF seems to only *process* data that is submitted from forms. I'm looking to simply place data into a form so that it can then be printed and sent out via postal mail!

Comment: No, FDF specify an XML format of the the data to be merged into a PDF document and then a new PDF is created with the data merged, see these PDFBox examples :  http://kickjava.com/src/org/pdfbox/ImportFDF.java.htm  and  http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/1.6.0/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/fdf/SetField.java/?v=source

Answer (score 6):

Please take a look at the chapter about interactive forms in the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html). It bundles the answers to questions such as:

- [How to fill out a pdf file programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108704/how-to-fill-out-a-pdf-file-programatically)
- [How can I flatten a XFA PDF Form using iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067250/how-can-i-flatten-a-xfa-pdf-form-using-itextsharp)
- [Checking off pdf checkbox with itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698771/checking-off-pdf-checkbox-with-itextsharp)
- [How to continue field output on a second page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853894/how-to-continue-field-output-on-a-second-page)
- [finding out required fields to fill in pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838945/finding-out-required-fields-to-fill-in-pdf-file)
- and so on...

Or you can watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YwDME0Fl1c) where I explain [how to use forms for reporting](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/using-forms-reporting) step by step.

See for instance:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
            new FileOutputStream(dest));
    AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
    fields.setField("name", "CALIFORNIA");
    fields.setField("abbr", "CA");
    fields.setField("capital", "Sacramento");
    fields.setField("city", "Los Angeles");
    fields.setField("population", "36,961,664");
    fields.setField("surface", "163,707");
    fields.setField("timezone1", "PT (UTC-8)");
    fields.setField("timezone2", "-");
    fields.setField("dst", "YES");
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: FYI, a commercial license is required for iText unless the application you're using it in is open source

Comment: @TimKuehn Your comment isn't accurate. You claim "The link**s** on this answer don't work anymore." I tested them all and they all worked but the last one. In the case of the last one, I got a Page Not Found page with a search box. When I entered "reporting" in the search box, the first hit pointed at the desired page.

Comment: The OP is doing pro bono development for a food pantry (food bank). I think commercial software development is *really* not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void fillPDF()
{
    
     try {
            PDDocument pDDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("D:/pdf/pdfform.pdf")); // pdfform.pdf is input file
            PDAcroForm pDAcroForm = pDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
            
                    
         PDField field = pDAcroForm.getField("Given Name Text Box"); 

          field.setValue("firstname"); 
          field = pDAcroForm.getField("Family Name Text Box");
          field.setValue("lastname");
          field = pDAcroForm.getField("Country Combo Box");
          field.setValue("Country");
          System.out.println("country combo" );
          field = pDAcroForm.getField(" Driving License Check Box");
          
          field = pDAcroForm.getField("Favourite Colour List Box");
        System.out.println("country combo"+ field.isRequired());
          pDDocument.save("D:/pdf/pdf-java-output.pdf");
             pDDocument.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: This is from PDF Box. https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android