# How to determine “Checked” value for Checkboxes (from GetAppearanceStates)

Tags: itext

I have a question about checkbox fields, and *consistently* figuring out which value to use for a checked state.

I have been searching, and shelled out $50 for the iText in Action book and scoured it as well.  The book is great, but it didn’t answer this particular question.

I know to call GetAppearanceStates(fieldName) to get the domain of possible values for a particular field, and know to call SetField(fieldName, value) to check the box.

My question is: how do I **definitively** know WHICH of the values returned by GetAppearanceStates is the “Check” value, or the value I need to use to check the field?

To be fair, most forms I've seen use values like: True,False,On,Off,Yes,No... but if I understand things correctly, the creator of the PDF can specify any arbitrary value.

Is there a way to find out, for sure, WHICH of the values returned by GetAppearanceStates is the "check" value?

The examples I saw seemed to indicate the first element in the array would be the one to check it, but apparently that was just me reading too much into the example, because I’ve run into a document where the first element is “Off” (and the second is “Yes”).  Before I dive in and write code that explicitly looks for string values like True,Yes,On,Oui,Yuppers,Check… or whatever, I thought I’d see if there is a better way!  I really hope I’m missing something.

Again, I'm working only with checkbox fields here.

Thanks for any help at all!

Comment: GAH - Sorry guys, messed up on the title, it should have been "ITextSharp - how to determine “Checked” value for **Checkboxes** (from GetAppearanceStates)" - not Textboxes

Comment: See Bruno Lowagie's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698771/checking-off-pdf-checkbox-with-itextsharp

Comment: Bruno's answer explains how to get the appearance states (`GetAppearanceStates`), which is already mentioned in the question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO 32000-1:2008 ("PDF 1.7 spec") says in 12.7.4.2.3 ("Check Boxes"):

> The appearance for the off state is optional but, if present, shall be
>   stored in the appearance dictionary under the name **Off**. **Yes**
>   should be used as the name for the on state.

So if there's an appearance for the unchecked state, it has to be **Off**.  The **Yes** for the checked state is a recommendation; it can be named differently.

If 2 arbitrary names are used for checked and unchecked, you can't reliably determine which should be used for checked and which for unchecked.

Comment: You cannot rely on constants "Off", "Yes", "No", etc if want to write fail-safe code. (For example I have a PDF where "No" suprisingly means the checked state.) Instead one should analyze control's Appearance States.

Comment: Indeed, you should not use such constants, but that's already covered in the question: `GetAppearanceStates`. The actual question is how to determine what the results from `GetAppearanceStates` mean. If a PDF does not follow the PDF spec in using **Off** for the off state, you don't know what the appearance states mean.