# how to check checkbox on iTextPdf?

Tags: java, itext

how to check checkbox on iText?

```
form.setField("pt_gender_female", "On");
form.setField("pt_gender_female", true);
```

I did couple of trial and error but none of these worked. I searched but didn't find the perfect answer.

Comment: Try to get String[] states = form.getAppearanceStates("pt_gender_female"); And then set the state according to the options in this String[]

Comment: Please download the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html). It contains the answers to many questions including [Checking off pdf checkbox with itextsharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698771/checking-off-pdf-checkbox-with-itextsharp) (The answer is about iTextSharp, but it also applies to iText).

Answer (score 8):

```
String states[] = stamper.getAcroFields().getAppearanceStates("pt_gender_female");
form.setField("pt_gender_female",states[1]);
```

I tried the abode snipet. It checked the checkbox.

Comment: Beware of ArrayOutOfBounds - the `states` may contain just a single element. "Yes" in my case. Noticed that after edited a PDF by Acrobat DC.

Answer (score 0):

That's how it's done in itextPdf

```
form.setField("pt_gender_female","Yes"); // to check it
form.setField("pt_gender_female","Off"); // to uncheck it
```

Comment: The **Off** for the off state is required but **Yes** for the on state merely is recommended, not required, it could be anything. Thus, for the on state one had better inspect the available appearance states of the check box as hinted at by @Eleven's answer.

Comment: I checked the array values, they were 2. Off and Yes, do they get changed?

Comment: Different check boxes may have different on state values. For the same check box the on state value usually will remain.