# GetAppearanceStates() in itextsharp

Tags: itext, collection-radio-buttons

Im getting possible values of checkbox from a dynamic pdf(pdf is uploaded by user at runtime)using GetAppearanceState(). But how to refer the off value and not based on array nos as suggested by @Bruno Lowagie comments on below post.
Reference : 
[Checking off pdf checkbox with itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698771/checking-off-pdf-checkbox-with-itextsharp)

The Off value should always reflect the off state. The order doesn't matter. So you shouldn't count on the 1st state to be the "uncheck" state. – Bruno Lowagie Apr 22 '16 at 17:35

My code

    `string[] checkboxStates = myAcrofields.GetAppearanceStates(strChkboxName);

    string strChecked = checkboxStates[0];    //Here i want to refer array 
    ["Off"].
    string strUnchecked = checkboxStates[1];
    if (my_fieldproperties[5] == "true")

        myAcrofields.SetField(my_fieldproperties[8], strChecked);
    else
        myAcrofields.SetField(my_fieldproperties[8], strUnchecked);`

Comment: no one to help?