# Adding table to existing PDF on the same page with tagging - ITEXT

Tags: java, pdf, itext

this question is continuation of the link
[Adding table to existing PDF on the same page - ITEXT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590487/adding-table-to-existing-pdf-on-the-same-page-itext)

this link proved the way to create table in existing PDf , but the issue is the generated table are not " tagged " .

Comment: What have you tried? Do know that this isn't a trivial use of iText

Comment: @Michaël Demey   1. I am reading the existing Pdf file (template) using PdfReader  2.created a stamper from the reader  3. created table (PdfPtable )  and added cells  4. created ColumnText ( ColumnText cl= new ColumnText(stamper.getovercontent(1)))  5.added the table to cl (ColumnText) 6. closed stamper and reader                                                                                 it creates a table in the existing Pdf file but that table is not tagged  as table .    FYI, my pdf file is already tagged