# itextsharp-insert dynamic table in existing pdf model

Tags: pdf, itext

now i face a problem that i need to add a dynamic table inside my pdf model. as far as i search the answer. they are all insert fixed length content(just like below link). I wonder know how can i insert a dynamic table(maybe different rows) into my pdf model and other content in model roll over accordingly? great appreciate if giving code sample.

[How to continue field output on a second page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853894/how-to-continue-field-output-on-a-second-page)

Comment: All content added to a PDF file is added at fixed absolute positions. You can't "insert" new content and expect the other content to reflow. PDF is not a word processing format. Please clarify, because currently your question sounds as if you're trying to do something that is impossible. It would be great if you could refer to ISO-32000-1 in your question so that there is no doubt about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm so glad to get your replay as you are an expert in the itext field and thanks a lot. According your replay, you mean if i want to add a table between Filed A and Field B, and if there's no space between them. the Field B will be override by the table, right? if i want to add table between two fields i need to leave enough space for the table, right?  Now my project need to add tables in existing pdf form which row account depends on records in database. and there are many similar situation. Is there any other way to achieve this? Sorry for my poor understanding for itextSharp.