# iText append table to PdfContentByte

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a pdf template. My task is to populate its fields and append table to the current page or to the new page if it doesn't fit.

I know how to add content at absolute positions, but it would be nice if I can get this values from `iText`

What I need is something like that

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, fileStream);
PdfContentByte content = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
ColumnText colText= new ColumnText(stamper.GetOverContent(1));

colText.SetSimpleColumn(pageSize.Left, pageSize.Bottom,
         pageSize.Right, pageSize.Top - content.PdfWriter.GetVerticalPosition(false));

colText.AddElement(table);
```

The problem is `content.PdfWriter.GetVerticalPosition` always returns `806` in my case. So is there any way to get content position or canvas height or something like that? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The `GetVerticalPosition()` method doesn't make any sense in the context of `PdfStamper`. You claim you have an existing PDF that contains fields. Why don't you ask those fields for their absolute position? As for the "new page if [the table] doesn't fit": you're creating that new page, so you know its dimensions, don't you? And if you know its dimensions, how come you don't know where to add the table? And didn't I explain all of this in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853894)?

Comment: Note: the duplicate question I refer to, can also be found on the official iText web site: [How to continue field output on a second page?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-continue-field-output-second-page) However, that was an answer to an old question involving iText 5. It seems that you're still using that version. In the new version iText 7 (first released two years ago; now at version 7.1.2), it's done [like this](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/interactive-forms/itext7-how-continue-field-output-second-page).

Comment: Note that the version you are currently using, is no longer supported (unless you're a paying customer with a support contract).

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie, Thank you for your answer.
Yes, I saw answer to the question you refering too, and it was very helpful so far. And I know I can get positions of fields, but what if the last element is `Paragraph` or `Chunk`?

I guess I can wrap everything into field "body" and then get its position. But I just thought there is a way to get content height or position of the last element in content that could be absent in `AcroFields`