# Converting FlateDecode pdf to xml format using xfa worker

Tags: xml, pdf, itext

We are encountering PDF files that are fillable dynamic  PDF forms containing user-supplied data. Forms are prepared with Adobe Live Cycle Designer modified with iText

PDF file consists of  objects  like this: 
"132 0 obj

((Filter/FlateDecode/First 99/Length 2814/N 13/Type/ObjStm))stream ......"

We'd like to extract the data the the user filled into the form

I have found  xfa worker library based on itext (converting xfaform pdf + data.xml into flattened xfa pdf)
[How can I flatten a XFA PDF Form using iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067250/how-can-i-flatten-a-xfa-pdf-form-using-itextsharp)
Can i with this library perform the reverse operation (extract pdf form data to xml file)?

Comment: Extracting stream contents should be possible with any general purpose PDF library.

Comment: found the tool PDF-XChange Viewer . Allows  export xfa form data with a huge amount of additional attributes.

Comment: found the tool PDF-XChange Viewer . Allows  export xfa form data with a huge amount of additional attributes into xml.
What is the most convenient way get rid of additional info and import this hierarchical xml data  into SQL SERVER or MS Access tables