# PDF with fillable form fields + "Save As" = PDF with fixed text - how?

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm creating a PDF using iTextSharp and it contains some fillable form fields.  What I need, is to somehow set it up so that when those form fields are filled in and the resulting PDF is saved (in one of the commercially-available PDF readers like Adobe's Reader), I need those form fields to be fixed text (no longer editable).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly what you are looking for is called "form flattening", see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27067449/231316)

Answer (score 0):

As a comment suggests, this sounds like "flattening the document".

The issue with that process is that it is not available in (Adobe) Reader; it would require Acrobat, or server-side help.

On the other hand, some mobile PDF viewers do actually offer flattening when saving.

The workaround for Reader is to set the fields to read-only when saving the document. You would do this in the willSave Document Action by looping through the fields and setting them to readonly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Print your document as PDF. This will flatten the file.

For this
1. Install Adobe PDF Printer or CutePDF or some similar tool.
2. From your document. Select File -> Print.
3. Select Printer as the tool you installed in Step 1.
4. Your document will be a flattened, non-editable PDF now.