# Filling existing pdf text fields using iText

Tags: itext

I have a pdf  document already created with some textfields.I can fill those text fields using Adobe reader and save those values with that file.

My problem is ,can i do that programmatically using iText?If it is possible ,please tell me where i can find some examples?

Comment: Whenever I see a question like this, I wonder: *is the official web site that hard to find?* Please answer this question: what can we do to improve the web site? Please explain in your own words why you didn't find any example on [developers.itextpdf.com](https://developers.itextpdf.com/). What can we do to improve that site? What is wrong with the [books](https://developers.itextpdf.com/books) we provide?

Answer (score 14):

That's explained in the [iText 7 Jump-start tutorial](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-for-net/), more specifically in [chapter 4](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-for-net/chapter-4-making-a-pdf-interactive-net):

This form:

[image]

Can be filled out like this:

```
PdfDocument pdf =
    new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields();
fields.get("name").setValue("James Bond");
fields.get("language").setValue("English");
fields.get("experience1").setValue("Off");
fields.get("experience2").setValue("Yes");
fields.get("experience3").setValue("Yes");
fields.get("shift").setValue("Any");
fields.get("info").setValue("I was 38 years old when I became an MI6 agent.");
// form.flattenFields();
pdf.close();
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

If you uncomment the line `form.flattenFields();` then you get this:

[image]

When the form is flattened, the fields are removed, and only the content is left.

If by any chance the PDF is a dynamic XFA form, then you should provide an XML stream, and you should read the FAQ: [How to fill out a pdf file programmatically? (Dynamic XFA)](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/interactive-forms/itext7-how-fill-out-pdf-file-programmatically-dynamic-xfa)

As you seem to be new to iText, it is assumed that you'll use the latest version of iText (which is iText 7) as opposed to a version that is being phased out (iText 5) or obsolete (all versions prior to iText 2). However, if for any reason you choose to use iText 5, then your question is a duplicate of [How to fill out a pdf file programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108704/how-to-fill-out-a-pdf-file-programatically) (in which case your question should be closed as a duplicate).